# ajax's success function not returning all rows from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the success function in ajax, everything was going well until I added a new row in my database table and the success function isn't returning that row only for some reason which is gender_id, this is my ajax function :

```js
function editProduct(productId = null) {
  if (productId) {
    $("#productId").remove();
    // remove text-error
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    // remove from-group error
    $(".form-group")
      .removeClass("has-error")
      .removeClass("has-success");
    // modal spinner
    $(".div-loading").removeClass("div-hide");
    // modal div
    $(".div-result").addClass("div-hide");

    $.ajax({
      url: "php_action/fetchSelectedProduct.php",
      type: "post",
      data: { productId: productId },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        // alert(response.product_image);
        // modal spinner
        $(".div-loading").addClass("div-hide");
        // modal div
        $(".div-result").removeClass("div-hide");

        $("#getProductImage").attr("src", "stock/" + response.product_image);

        $("#editProductImage").fileinput({});

        // product id
        $(".editProductFooter").append(
          '<input type="hidden" name="productId" id="productId" value="' +
            response.product_id +
            '" />'
        );
        $(".editProductPhotoFooter").append(
          '<input type="hidden" name="productId" id="productId" value="' +
            response.product_id +
            '" />'
        );

        // product name
        $("#editProductName").val(response.product_name);
        // quantity
        $("#editQuantity").val(response.quantity);
        // rate
        $("#editRate").val(response.price);
        // brand name
        $("#editBrandName").val(response.brand_id);
        // category name
        $("#editCategoryName").val(response.categories_id);

        $("#editGender").val(response.gender_id);

        // status
        $("#editProductStatus").val(response.active);

        // update the product data function
        $("#editProductForm")
          .unbind("submit")
          .bind("submit", function() {
            // form validation
            var productImage = $("#editProductImage").val();
            var productName = $("#editProductName").val();
            var quantity = $("#editQuantity").val();
            var rate = $("#editRate").val();
            var brandName = $("#editBrandName").val();
            var categoryName = $("#editCategoryName").val();
            var genderName = $("#editGender").val();
            var productStatus = $("#editProductStatus").val();

            if (productName == "") {
              $("#editProductName").after(
                '<p class="text-danger">Product Name field is required</p>'
              );
              $("#editProductName")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-error");
            } else {
              // remov error text field
              $("#editProductName")
                .find(".text-danger")
                .remove();
              // success out for form
              $("#editProductName")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-success");
            } // /else

            if (quantity == "") {
              $("#editQuantity").after(
                '<p class="text-danger">Quantity field is required</p>'
              );
              $("#editQuantity")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-error");
            } else {
              // remov error text field
              $("#editQuantity")
                .find(".text-danger")
                .remove();
              // success out for form
              $("#editQuantity")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-success");
            } // /else

            if (rate == "") {
              $("#editRate").after(
                '<p class="text-danger">Rate field is required</p>'
              );
              $("#editRate")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-error");
            } else {
              // remov error text field
              $("#editRate")
                .find(".text-danger")
                .remove();
              // success out for form
              $("#editRate")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-success");
            } // /else

            if (brandName == "") {
              $("#editBrandName").after(
                '<p class="text-danger">Brand Name field is required</p>'
              );
              $("#editBrandName")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-error");
            } else {
              // remov error text field
              $("#editBrandName")
                .find(".text-danger")
                .remove();
              // success out for form
              $("#editBrandName")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-success");
            } // /else

            if (categoryName == "") {
              $("#editCategoryName").after(
                '<p class="text-danger">Category Name field is required</p>'
              );
              $("#editCategoryName")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-error");
            } else {
              // remov error text field
              $("#editCategoryName")
                .find(".text-danger")
                .remove();
              // success out for form
              $("#editCategoryName")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-success");
            } // /else

            if (genderName == "") {
              $("#editGender").after(
                '<p class="text-danger">Category Name field is required</p>'
              );
              $("#editGender")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-error");
            } else {
              // remov error text field
              $("#editGender")
                .find(".text-danger")
                .remove();
              // success out for form
              $("#editGender")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-success");
            }

            if (productStatus == "") {
              $("#editProductStatus").after(
                '<p class="text-danger">Product Status field is required</p>'
              );
              $("#editProductStatus")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-error");
            } else {
              // remov error text field
              $("#editProductStatus")
                .find(".text-danger")
                .remove();
              // success out for form
              $("#editProductStatus")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-success");
            } // /else

            if (
              productName &&
              quantity &&
              rate &&
              brandName &&
              genderName &&
              categoryName &&
              productStatus
            ) {
              // submit loading button
              $("#editProductBtn").button("loading");

              var form = $(this);
              var formData = new FormData(this);

              $.ajax({
                url: form.attr("action"),
                type: form.attr("method"),
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
                  if (response.success == true) {
                    // submit loading button
                    $("#editProductBtn").button("reset");

                    $(
                      "html, body, div.modal, div.modal-content, div.modal-body"
                    ).animate({ scrollTop: "0" }, 100);

                    // shows a successful message after operation
                    $("#edit-product-messages").html(
                      '<div class="alert alert-success">' +
                        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>' +
                        '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> ' +
                        response.messages +
                        "</div>"
                    );

                    // remove the mesages
                    $(".alert-success")
                      .delay(500)
                      .show(10, function() {
                        $(this)
                          .delay(3000)
                          .hide(10, function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                          });
                      }); // /.alert

                    // reload the manage student table
                    manageProductTable.ajax.reload(null, true);

                    // remove text-error
                    $(".text-danger").remove();
                    // remove from-group error
                    $(".form-group")
                      .removeClass("has-error")
                      .removeClass("has-success");
                  } // /if response.success
                }
                // /success function
              }); // /ajax function
            } // /if validation is ok

            return false;
          }); // update the product data function

        // update the product image
        $("#updateProductImageForm")
          .unbind("submit")
          .bind("submit", function() {
            // form validation
            var productImage = $("#editProductImage").val();

            if (productImage == "") {
              $("#editProductImage")
                .closest(".center-block")
                .after(
                  '<p class="text-danger">Product Image field is required</p>'
                );
              $("#editProductImage")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-error");
            } else {
              // remov error text field
              $("#editProductImage")
                .find(".text-danger")
                .remove();
              // success out for form
              $("#editProductImage")
                .closest(".form-group")
                .addClass("has-success");
            } // /else

            if (productImage) {
              // submit loading button
              $("#editProductImageBtn").button("loading");

              var form = $(this);
              var formData = new FormData(this);

              $.ajax({
                url: form.attr("action"),
                type: form.attr("method"),
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(response) {
                  if (response.success == true) {
                    // submit loading button
                    $("#editProductImageBtn").button("reset");

                    $(
                      "html, body, div.modal, div.modal-content, div.modal-body"
                    ).animate({ scrollTop: "0" }, 100);

                    // shows a successful message after operation
                    $("#edit-productPhoto-messages").html(
                      '<div class="alert alert-success">' +
                        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>' +
                        '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> ' +
                        response.messages +
                        "</div>"
                    );

                    // remove the mesages
                    $(".alert-success")
                      .delay(500)
                      .show(10, function() {
                        $(this)
                          .delay(3000)
                          .hide(10, function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                          });
                      }); // /.alert

                    // reload the manage student table
                    manageProductTable.ajax.reload(null, true);

                    $(".fileinput-remove-button").click();

                    $.ajax({
                      url: "php_action/fetchProductImageUrl.php?i=" + productId,
                      type: "post",
                      success: function(response) {
                        $("#getProductImage").attr("src", response);
                      }
                    });

                    // remove text-error
                    $(".text-danger").remove();
                    // remove from-group error
                    $(".form-group")
                      .removeClass("has-error")
                      .removeClass("has-success");
                  } // /if response.success
                } // /success function
              }); // /ajax function
            } // /if validation is ok

            return false;
          }); // /update the product image
      } // /success function
    }); // /ajax to fetch product image
  } else {
    alert("error please refresh the page");
  }
} // /edit product function
```

, and this is the sql query `fetchSelectedProduct` I'm using to fetch data from the database :

```
<?php   

require_once 'core.php';

$productId = $_POST['productId'];

$sql = "SELECT product_id, product_name, product_image, brand_id, categories_id, quantity, price, active, status, gender_id FROM product WHERE product_id = $productId";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) { 
 $row = $result->fetch_array();
} // if num_rows

$connect->close();

echo json_encode($row);
```

does anyone know what's the problem with my code? I tried to fix it and I couldn't..

Comment: The simplest way I would try to debug is to open phpmyadmin if you use one, and put the SQL query into `SQL` tab there replacing the variable with some random id. That usually shows very precisely where your error actually is, maybe it is a typo or something. By the way, note that your code is not secure, use prepared statements instead of direct query with parameters.

Comment: @Danielius i tried it and everything is going well , and i'll change my queries to the prepared statements ones. Thanks.

Comment: Please remove anything that isn't directly related to receiving and handling the data/rows. That's too much unnecessary code with 4 `$.ajax()` calls - [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)

Answer (score -1):

Almost certain is the ajax cache so just add:

```
cache: false
```

to your calls, or add new parameter to the request uri:

```
'?t=' + Date.now();
```

Comment: _"Almost certain..."_ - The requests are `post`s which are not cached or already have `cache: false`

Comment: Yes, `not cacheable, unless the response includes appropriate Cache-Control or Expires header fields`... and it happened not once, but several times with IE and iOS - they simply cached it. While everything worked fine in Firefox I got many complains from people using Safari on Mac and iOS.